# JSON column formatting for adding hyperlinks broken after recent Microsoft Lists update - only effects ?env=WebViewList view

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

Previously, we created links in a 'Single Line of Text' column via JSON column formatting.

This basic functionality is documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#turn-field-values-into-hyperlinks-basic

And the example they provide is:

```js
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + @currentField"
   }
}
```

A simple example without the dynamic content would therefore be:

```js
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "TEST",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "https://google.com"
   }
}
```

After the recent Microsoft List update that Microsoft rolled out, documented here:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-lists-easier-better-faster-stronger/ba-p/3806075

clicking on the links that our JSON column formatting generated does not open the links.

When we click on the links, nothing happens.

To clarify, the examples provided above do work, but the custom JSON column formatting that used to work for us, no longer does.

The links do work if we REMOVE the `?env=WebViewList` suffix from the list URL.

This undesired behaviour is happening on all sites in all lists in our tenant.

**Steps To Reproduce**

**01)**  Create a Microsoft List

**02)**  Go to the list and ensure it has the suffix `?env=WebViewList`
(so that it is displayed in the modern 'Microsoft Lists' look), eg:

```
https://<your-tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<your-site>/Lists/<your-list>/AllItems.aspx?env=WebViewList
```

(Note:  this issue can be reproduced in both personal Microsoft Lists and those stored in SharePoint Sites).

**03)**  Create a column in the list of type 'Single Line of Text'.

**04)**  Click on the column heading and select `Column Settings` > `Format this column` > `Advanced mode`

**05)**  Paste the following code and click Save

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "https://www.google.com",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "style": {
    "text-decoration": "none"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDark--hover",
        "title": "Click Me"
      },
      "style": {
        "border": "none",
        "background-color": "transparent",
        "cursor": "pointer"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": "Attach",
            "class": "ms-font"
          },
          "style": {
            "padding-right": "2px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "txtContent": "Click Me"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**06)**  Add an item to the list so that you can see the generated link

**07)**  Click on the generated link and nothing will happen

**08)**  (If you are testing on a list within a SharePoint Site, remove the `?env=WebViewList` from the list URL and reload the list and the link will work).

**Update:**

After further investigation, if I click to the right of the link text, the link DOES work, but if I click on the link text itself the link DOES NOT work.